# Docker container exited error 126. How to solve it?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

In my side project I use 4 containers (backend, frontend, db and redis) and since yesterday the backend container stops with an error 126

The error in the docker logs:

```
backend          | yarn run v1.22.15
backend          | $ tsc-watch --onSuccess "yarn start"
backend          | /bin/sh: 1: tsc-watch: Permission denied
backend          | error Command failed with exit code 126.
```

The dockerfile looks like this:

```
# ================ #
#    Base Stage    #
# ================ #
FROM node:18-buster-slim as base

WORKDIR /opt/backend

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y --no-install-recommends && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential python3 libfontconfig1 dumb-init && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--enable-source-maps"

ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]

# =================== #
#  Development Stage  #
# =================== #
FROM base as development

ENV NODE_ENV="development"

RUN chown -R node:node /opt/backend/

USER node

CMD [ "yarn", "run", "docker:watch"]
```

The only thing what's changed that I ran an `apt-get upgrade` on my computer. Before it it ran without any issue.

How to solve this problem?

**Update:**

When I open the container with `docker exec -it backend bash` to run the command manually I've got the same error.

`tsc-watch` needs the `src/` dir and on successfull compile it creates the `dist/` dir

This command logs me in as `root`.

The owner:group of these files are node:node and the permissions are 664 (the directories are 775)

Comment: try to use ```docker run --privileged...```

Comment: The error seems to indicate a problem with the tsc-watch command, what happens if you run that yourself in the container. What files does this command need to access, read or write, and what are the permissions on those files vs what user are you running as?

Comment: Hi @BMitch , I've updated the description with the info you've asked